# SVG icon system with angular-cli

Tags: angular, svg, typescript, angular-cli, svg-sprite

I have an angular2 project which was created via angular-cli. In webpack there is a loader to load the svg sprite and also to generate that sprite from list of svgs. But how do I can use this functionality in my current project when angular-cli doesn't allow me to change webpack.config?

Thanks.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

## Use [svg-sprite](https://www.npmjs.com/package/svg-sprite)

### 1. `npm install --save-dev svg-sprite`

### 2. Put your svgs in `src/svgs`

### 3. Add `sprite-config.json` to your project root

```
{
    "dest": "src/",
    "mode": {
        "css": {
            "dest": "sprites",
            "render": {
                "scss": {
                    "dest": "_sprite.scss"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### 4. Add a script to `package.json`

```
"sprites": "svg-sprite --config sprite-config.json src/svgs/*.svg"
```

### 5. Add `@import` to your main `styles.scss`

```
@import './sprites/sprite';
```

### 6. Run script using `npm run sprites`

### Optional: create a build script

Add this to your scripts to build in one step

```
"start": "npm run sprites && ng serve",
"build": "npm run sprites && ng build --prod"
```

Comment: This is just awesome! Thank you very much.

Comment: Great! If you've found this helpful please consider up voting/accepting the answer. Thank you!

Comment: Well at the moment I can't vote/accept the answer. My reputation is a bit low for that now. I'm new here.

Comment: This generates a stylesheet with classes, referencing the svg's as a background. I would prefer no css to be generated, and just use this syntax:

    <svg class="icon"><use xlink:href="#arrow-circle-right"></use></svg>

I prefer this approach because i find it easier to scale the svgs like this.

Comment: @Davy So have you found a way to use no-css approach with angular cli?

Comment: Well, yes, but not in a very elegant way

Comment: @Davy instead of 'css' mode that was provided in the example use 'symbol' mode.

Comment: I am also looking for a non-CSS way to use SVG sprites in my Angular app. I have posted a question that targets this specific issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50459291

Comment: nice solution, but do you know of a way that this build would be integrated to `ng serve` so that a change in `svg` files would result in browser reload?